# Successful payment in Paypal Sandbox even without funds

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently trying my app to notify the buyer if he/she has no funds. But every time I use a paypal test account without funds, the payment still proceeds. What could be the cause of this error? I have negative testing on for my facilitator account.

Comment: What do you mean "no funds"? Most PayPal payments are not funded from PayPal balances. But if an account really has no *funding sources*, ie no way to get money, then it should not be able to make a payment (including in sandbox).

Comment: I see. So if I have a card linked but have 0 PayPal balance, PayPal will charge it from the card right? I just wonder, I've tested countless times already. All of them succeeded but only a few of them made it to my facilitator account's recent activity. ie, I tested 10+ times already but I can only see 5 from my recent activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a credit card attached to the sandbox account it will use that as the funding source.

With negative testing, though, what you do is send a specific amount in the transaction request in order to get a specific error code back for testing.

[See this documentation for more details](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/).